# MYSQL wrong results output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables with the following data:

1st table called connections where `connections.username1` is the one who follows and `connections.username2` is the one who is followed.

It has the following rows:

```
connections.username1 | connections.username2
      mikha           |          guy
      guy             |          maricela
      maricela        |          guy
```

2nd table called questions. It has a column for for the asker called `questions.asker_username` and another for the one who receives the question called `questions.target_username`. When the asker is called "sys.tem" and the target called "every.one", it's considered a global question and could be answered by all members.

Anonymous users could ask and their ip is recorded as the `asker_username`.

It has the following rows:

```
questions.id | questions.asker_username | questions.target_username | questions.question
  1          |      mikha               |       guy                 | what's your name?                             
  2          |      mikha               |       maricela            | What's your age?
  3          |      guy                 |       mikha               | what's your name?
  4          |      maricela            |       guy                 | favorite food?
  5          |      xx.xx.xxx.xx        |       mikha               | favorite pet?
  6          |      xx.xx.xxx.xx        |       guy                 | first name?
  7          |      xx.xx.xxx.xx        |       maricela            | first name?   
  8          |      sys.tem             |       every.one           | what's ur name?
  9          |      sys.tem             |       every.one           | favorite movie?  
 10          |      sys.tem             |       every.one           | favorite game?
```

The 3rd table is called answers. The id in the answers table is the same as the question id. This table has a column for id and username and answer.

```
answers.id  |  answers.username | answers.answer
   1        |       guy         | my name is guy
   2        |     maricela      | my name is maricela
   3        |       mikha       | my name is mikha
   4        |       guy         | pizza        
   8        |       guy         | guy is my name
   8        |       maricela    | maricela is my name   
   9        |       maricela    | avatar
```

I want a query which combines the following conditions related to "mikha" and the people he follows:

1) `questions.asker_username` is NOT "mikha"

2)  `questions.target_username` is either "mikha" or any of the users he follows.

3) If `questions.target_username` equals to "every.one" and answered by "mikha", show the question.

4) If `questions.target_username` equals to "every.one" and answered by any of the people whom "mikha" follows, show the question and its answer. If no answer by the users whom "mikha" follow, don't show the question.

5) If `questions.target_username` equals to "every.one" and is not answered by any one at all, show the question once.

6) If `questions.target_username` equals to "every.one" and is not answered by "mikha" and not answered by any of the people he follows, show the question only once.

I use the following query:

```
SELECT questions.id,answers.id,questions.asker_username,questions.target_username,
    answers.username,questions.question,answers.answer 
FROM questions 
    LEFT JOIN answers ON (questions.id = answers.id) 
    LEFT JOIN connections ON connections.username1 = 'mikha' 
        AND (questions.target_username = connections.username2 
            OR questions.asker_username = connections.username2 
            OR connections.username2 = answers.username) 
WHERE questions.asker_username <> 'mikha' 
    AND (questions.target_username = 'mikha' 
        OR questions.target_username = connections.username2 
        OR (questions.target_username = 'every.one' 
            AND (answers.username = 'mikha' 
                OR answers.username = connections.username2
                OR answers.username IS NULL)
            )
        ) 
GROUP BY questions.id,answers.username
```

The result I expect:

```
questions.id | answers.id | questions.asker_username | questions.target_username | answers.username | questions.question | answers.answer
    3        |      3     |        guy               |          mikha            |    mikha         | what's your name?  | my name is mikha
    4        |      4     |        maricela          |          guy              |    guy           | favorite food?     | pizza
    5        |      5     |        xx.xx.xxx.xx      |          mikha            |    NULL          | favorite pet?      | NULL
    6        |      6     |        xx.xx.xxx.xx      |          guy              |    NULL          | first name?        | NULL        
    8        |      8     |        sys.tem           |         every.one         |    NULL          | what's ur name?    | NULL 
    8        |      8     |        sys.tem           |         every.one         |    guy           | what's ur name?    | guy is my name
    9        |      9     |        sys.tem           |         every.one         |    NULL          | favorite movie?    | NULL       
    10       |      10    |        sys.tem           |         every.one         |    NULL          | favorite game?     | NULL
```

The result I actually get:

```
 questions.id | answers.id | questions.asker_username | questions.target_username | answers.username | questions.question | answers.answer
    3        |      3     |        guy               |          mikha            |    mikha         | what's your name?  | my name is mikha
    4        |      4     |        maricela          |          guy              |    guy           | favorite food?     | pizza
    5        |      5     |        xx.xx.xxx.xx      |          mikha            |    NULL          | favorite pet?      | NULL
    6        |      6     |        xx.xx.xxx.xx      |          guy              |    NULL          | first name?        | NULL        
    8        |      8     |        sys.tem           |         every.one         |    guy           | what's ur name?    | guy is my name           
    10       |      10    |        sys.tem           |         every.one         |    NULL          | favorite game?     | NULL
```

I built a scheme on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29929e/1 to show you the results I actually get

Thanks :)

Comment: That's very nice problem description, indeed, but due to SO rules, what is the question (I don't see any questionmark)?

Comment: What's the correct query to achieve the expected results?? this is driving me crazy for over a week :( thanks :)

Comment: Requirement 4 and 6 contradict each other. 4 says: Don't show answer if no answer from people mikha follows. 6 says: Show answer if no answer from people mikhe follows.

Comment: This is a global question, so if 'mikha' is following a lot of people, the question will be displayed tons of times on the feed even if it's not answered. So, i want to show it only once for "mikha" whether it's answered or not and show it again each time it's answered by any of the people "mikha" follows. Thanks :)

Comment: Just a little suggestion (it doesn't solve your problem but you might want to bear it in mind).  Using the usernames as a primary key can be problematic.  What if a user wants to change their username?  You'll have to change every place where that username is referenced.  Also, querying and joining on string values is relatively slow compared to the same on integers.  You might want to have an immutable integer ID for the primary key and simply make the username a unique column instead.

Comment: The username is unchangeable..so no problem about that..there is already a unique id for each user..may be I will try this suggestion. Didn't know that there is difference between joining using integers and strings. Thanks :)

Comment: @GordonM I do not know of any web application where user can change his username (that he uses for logging in)... Though I know of applications where `displayname` is used - and that could be changed...

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: Why don't you expect the answers from maricela and mikha for question 8? According to your question those answers exist (but the one from mikha doesn't exist in the fiddle). Furthermore, `answers.id = 8` makes no sense for the row with no answer.

Comment: I don't show the question and answer instance by maricela, because mikha isn't following maricela, so this instance should be ignored. Instead I want only the one by guy (because he answered and mikha follows him) and the other one with answer as null so that mikha can also answer the question.

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: And why don't you want the answer from mikha himself? It should be shown according to requirement 3.

Comment: sorry this was a mistake. I just remove the answer by mikha. So it's not answered by mikha that's why I want the 8th row the first time, so that mikha can answer the question.

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: And what would you want as the result if there was an answer by mikha and guy?

Comment: If it's answered by mikha and guy, simply show the question and answer once for mikha and once for guy. Maricela isn't followed by mikha, that's why her question/answer instance shouldn't be shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that - in some circumstances - you want to show a question twice when only one matching answer exists. I quote:

> So, i want to show it only once for "mikha" whether it's answered or not and show it again each time it's answered by any of the people "mikha" follows

This duplication makes things pretty hard.

I tried to solve that with a `UNION` and it seems to work. However, I still haven't fully understood your requirements...

Anyway, here we go:

```
select * from
(
  select
    q.id as q_id, a.id as a_id, q.asker_username,
    q.target_username, a.username, q.question, a.answer
  from
    questions q
    left outer join answers a on q.id = a.id
  where
    q.asker_username <> 'mikha' 
    and
    (
      q.target_username = 'mikha'
      or q.target_username in
         (select username2 from connections where username1 = 'mikha')
      or
      (
        q.target_username = 'every.one'
        and
        (
          a.username = 'mikha'
          or a.username in
             (select username2 from connections where username1 = 'mikha')
          or a.id is null
        )
      )
    )
  union
  select
    q.id as q_id, NULL as a_id, q.asker_username,
    q.target_username, NULL, q.question, NULL
  from
    questions q
  where
    q.asker_username <> 'mikha' 
    and q.target_username = 'every.one'
    and not exists (select id
                    from answers
                    where
                      id = q.id
                      and username = 'mikha'
                    )
) r
order by q_id;
```

Test it live:
[With answer from mikha for question 8](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2b8d/9)
[Without answer from mikha for question 8](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29929e/125)

Comment: I made a mistake and just edited my original question. I had row 8 answered by mikha. I removed it to avoid confusion. Now row 8 should be shown twice, one for mikha as he hasn't answered yet and once for guy as he is followed by mikha and he has given an answer. maricela answer is ignored as she isn't followed by mikha

Comment: This one is working well :) but isn't there any way to do the above query without unions and subqueries? both are performance hit when scaling. Thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: I don't think so.

Comment: You don't think there is another way or you don't they are performance hit??

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: I don't think there is another way.

Comment: Ok what would you recommend more, using UNION or from inside the PHP while loop, select the second query as a separate one??

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: `UNION` as it does more than just append stuff - that would be `UNION ALL`. `UNION` additionally is an implicit `distinct`.

Comment: One last question, why did you use subqueries instead of join? like you didn't join the connections table. Thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: A join would have multiplied the results - I am not sure the result would have been the same. You can try it. If it works, good :-)

Answer (score 5):

OK, lets start from the simplest one (Your first rule):

```
SELECT q.id, a.id, q.asker_username, q.target_username, a.username, q.question, a.answer 
FROM questions q 
    LEFT JOIN answers a ON q.id = a.id  
WHERE q.asker_username <> 'mikha' 
GROUP BY q.id,a.username
```

Now lets add Your second rule - now more complexity is added...

```
SELECT q.id, a.id, q.asker_username, q.target_username, a.username, q.question, a.answer 
FROM questions q 
    LEFT JOIN answers a ON q.id = a.id 
WHERE q.asker_username <> 'mikha' 
    AND q.target_username = 'mikha' 
        OR q.target_username IN (
            SELECT username2 
            FROM connections 
            WHERE username1 = 'mikha'
        )
GROUP BY q.id,a.username
```

Now the third rule (for everyone answered by mikha):

```
SELECT q.id, a.id, q.asker_username, q.target_username, a.username, q.question, a.answer 
FROM questions q 
    LEFT JOIN answers a ON q.id = a.id 
WHERE q.asker_username <> 'mikha' 
    AND q.target_username = 'mikha' 
        OR q.target_username IN (
            SELECT username2 
            FROM connections 
            WHERE username1 = 'mikha'
        )
        OR (q.target_username = 'every.one' AND a.username = 'mikha')
GROUP BY q.id,a.username
```

Now for the fourth rule:

```
SELECT q.id, a.id, q.asker_username, q.target_username, a.username, q.question, a.answer 
FROM questions q 
    LEFT JOIN answers a ON q.id = a.id 
WHERE q.asker_username <> 'mikha' 
    AND q.target_username = 'mikha' 
        OR q.target_username IN (
            SELECT username2 
            FROM connections 
            WHERE username1 = 'mikha'
        )
        OR (q.target_username = 'every.one' AND a.username = 'mikha')
        OR (q.target_username = 'every.one' AND a.username IN (
            SELECT username2 
            FROM connections 
                INNER JOIN answers ON answers.username = connections.username2
                    AND answers.answers IS NOT NULL
            WHERE username1 = 'mikha'
        ))
GROUP BY q.id,a.username
```

Fifth rule (Jesus!):

```
SELECT q.id, a.id, q.asker_username, q.target_username, a.username, q.question, a.answer 
FROM questions q 
    LEFT JOIN answers a ON q.id = a.id 
WHERE q.asker_username <> 'mikha' 
    AND q.target_username = 'mikha' 
        OR q.target_username IN (
            SELECT username2 
            FROM connections 
            WHERE username1 = 'mikha'
        )
        OR (q.target_username = 'every.one' AND a.username = 'mikha')
        OR (q.target_username = 'every.one' AND a.username IN (
            SELECT username2 
            FROM connections 
                INNER JOIN answers ON answers.username = connections.username2
                    AND answers.answers IS NOT NULL
            WHERE username1 = 'mikha'
        ))
        OR (q.target_username = 'every.one' AND a.answer IS NULL)
GROUP BY q.id,a.username
```

And for the last one:

```
SELECT q.id, a.id, q.asker_username, q.target_username, a.username, q.question, a.answer 
FROM questions q 
    LEFT JOIN answers a ON q.id = a.id 
WHERE q.asker_username <> 'mikha' 
    AND q.target_username = 'mikha' 
        OR q.target_username IN (
            SELECT username2 
            FROM connections 
            WHERE username1 = 'mikha'
        )
        OR (q.target_username = 'every.one' AND a.username = 'mikha')
        OR (q.target_username = 'every.one' AND a.username IN (
            SELECT username2 
            FROM connections 
                INNER JOIN answers ON answers.username = connections.username2
                    AND answers.answers IS NOT NULL
            WHERE username1 = 'mikha'
        ))
        OR (q.target_username = 'every.one' AND a.answer IS NULL)
        OR (q.target_username = 'every.one' AND a.username NOT IN (
            SELECT username2 
            FROM connections 
                INNER JOIN answers ON answers.username = connections.username2
                    AND answers.answers IS NOT NULL
            WHERE username1 = 'mikha'
        ))
GROUP BY q.id,a.username
```

I think that rule 4 and rule 6 are kinda against each other (contradicting could be said) and when used in one query it would have the same effect as if omitted...

I didn't test any of the queries but I believe they work.

Comment: Hey Shady :) thanks for your efforts but it's giving me the same output I get and the first case now is ignored for some reason. You can test the sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29929e/101 Thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel Pardon me, I have not so much time to test the queries and look for missing parts. Please, follow my example - "deatomize" Your query into the simplest parts and add them one at a time as I did until You find the results You desire. :-) Always use this technique when building complex queries - start with the simplest one and continue building one step at a time.

Comment: believe me...i have been trying this for over a week with no avail :( there is something i'm missing in the query. I can't achieve that's why I had to ask..thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that one of the main issues with your starting point is that you need to join your connections table twice - once for answers and once for questions.

The code below gives inline comments on what it's doing. I would also agree with other answers in suggesting that numeric id fields would be better for comparisons - and I would also advise putting a unique rowid field on the answers table (better still, change `id` to `question_id` and then make `id` the unique field.

```
SELECT DISTINCT q.id,a.id,q.asker_username,q.target_username,a.username,q.question,a.answer
FROM questions q
  /* Answers */
  LEFT JOIN answers a ON (q.id=a.id)
  /* connection entries where the person being followed is the target */
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT username2 FROM connections WHERE username1='mikha') c_q
    ON c_q.username2=q.target_username
  /* connection entries where the person being followed answered the question */
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT username2 FROM connections WHERE username1='mikha') c_a
    ON c_a.username2=a.username 
  /* Own answers */
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM answers WHERE username='mikha') a_own 
    ON (q.id=a_own.id) 
  WHERE 
  /* Asker not mikha, target is mikha or followed user - rules 1,2 */
  (q.asker_username <> 'mikha'
  AND (q.target_username='mikha' OR c_q.username2 IS NOT NULL))
  OR
  /* sys.tem/every.one, answered by mikha - rule 3 */
  (q.target_username='every.one' AND a.username='mikha')
  OR
  /* Rules 4, 5 & 6 combine to give "show the answer at least once, and once for every followed user who answered" - here we select any every.one messages where mikha didn't answer and nor did the people he follows */
  (q.target_username='every.one' AND a_own.id IS NULL AND c_a.username2 IS NULL);
```

It doesn't give you two rows for question 8, but I couldn't really work out why you wanted that. The issue there is that it's not clear which of your rules are additive and which are combinatory. If you can explain which rules should "add" a row rather than just providing another reason to show a row, maybe we can get you that extra row for question 8 too.

Comment: Ok..shortly..the problem lies mainly when the question is a global one (target = every.one). User (mikha) could be following a lot of users like 1000 users. In this case the global question would appear 1000 times on mikha's feed which just doesn't make sense. That's why I want to show it only when it's answered to avoid duplicates. I want to also show it once again for 1 time so that "mikha" can answer it or if it's answered by mikha show the question with answer (that's why show the row 8 two times, one for mikha and one because it's answered by guy whom mikha follows).

Comment: another case when the global question isn't answered at all by any member on the site, show it once so that "mikha" can answer it (this is row 10). Another case when it's not answered by mikha nor the people he follows, show it also once so that mikha can answer (this is row 9)